# How to reference UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspx-user-control

I work on an application that has a particular design flaw, where some content should be accessible in multiple areas of the application depending on what role(s) a user may have.  In the past this has led developers to copy and paste pages into different places with slightly different names, which ultimately leads to bugs when things get out of sync and also just feels yucky.

I want to try to abstract out the (99%) common code into its own class, however the code behind each page references various controls on the page.  I can't seem to figure out how to reference the UserControl classes.

For example a page might have

```
<%@ Register Src="~/uc/ResearchParamBar.ascx" TagName="ResearchParamBar" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
...
<uc1:ResearchParamBar ID="ResearchParamBar1" runat="server"/>
```

And the code behind would have

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // wire the event to the destination user control handler
    ResearchParamBar1.SourcePageID = ObjectID;
    ...
 }
```

The user control is defined like

```
public partial class ResearchParamBar : BaseUserControl
```

I was trying to pass a ResearchParamBar in the constructor to the abstract class, but it's not clear to me how to reference that class.

> The type or namespace name 'ResearchParamBar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public abstract class SummaryBase : WRBasePage
{

    public abstract string ObjectID
    {
        get;
    }

    //Cannot figure out how to reference ResearchParamBar
    private ResearchParamBar ResearchParamBar1;

    public SummaryBase(ResearchParamBar researchParamBar)
    {
        ResearchParamBar1 = researchParamBar;
    }
```

Comment: The error doesn't really have anything to do with the markup in the aspx, but just with the C# code itself.  You're trying to reference a type, but it's not clear to the compiler where to find that type.  Can you try fully-qualifying the type name?  Or adding a `using` directive to the top of the C# file which references the full namespace which contains the type?

Comment: When Visual Studio creates the UserControl it doesn't put it in a namespace, so I'm not sure how I should reference it.

Typically the suggestions will know how to add a using, but in this case it doesn't.

Comment: How was your user control created?  Surely it has a class in its code-behind?  Does that class really have no namespace?

Comment: It's old but I'm pretty confident whomever created it just used the GUI to add a new user control.  All of the UserControls in this solution look the same.

public partial class ClassName:BaseUserControl

no namespaces.

Comment: Is BaseUserControl this your abstract class?
Please add the failing code.

Comment: Added to my original post.  Can't figure out how to reference ResearchParamBar in SummaryBase my abstract class.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of <%@ Register you can use in the code behind?